# How do I send Serialized data from one activity to another activity recyclerview

Tags: android, retrofit

How do I send data from one activity to another activity recyclerview adapter.
I am getting data using retrofit 2 and sent it through put extra here am getting error unable to marsh

```
private void callApigetCategoryItems() {
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<CategoryResponse> call = apiService.getCategoryResult(1);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Response<CategoryResponse> response) {
            List<ProductsItem> products = response.body().getData().getProducts();
            for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
                String stockCategoryName = products.get(i).getStockCategoryName();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "" + stockCategoryName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("category", (Serializable) products);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

List<ProductsItem> productsItemList = (List<ProductsItem>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("category");
```

> Error:   Process: com.adverscribe.bookyourstock, PID: 18514
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
>   ProductsItem{stock_division_id = '0',cover_status =
>   '1',listing_image_color_id = '3',listing_id = '4',listing_detail_id =
>   '3',stock_fit_id = '0',frabic_blend_mix = '',seller_brand_id =
>   '0',listing_size_id = '4',vendor_style_no = 'ABCD',stock_size_status =
>   '1',style_discription = 'AV',total_stock = '2',size_created_date =
>   '2018-01-12 12:25:48',stock_color_id = '1',stock_pattern_id =
>   '0',stock_subcategory_status = '1',listing_status = '0',seller_id =
>   '1',product_usp = '',stock_color_status = '1',stock_size_name =
>   'M',listing_updated_date = '2018-01-23 09:20:48',stock_category_name =
>   'T-Shirts',stock_size_id = '4',stock_division_name = 'Men',mrp =
>   '550',stock_quantity = '1',stock_sleeve_id = '0',stock_subcategory_id
>   = '1',stock_fabric_id = '0',stock_start_date = '2017-12-22',stock_subcategory_name = 'Polo',active_status =
>   '0',color_id = '1',stock_color_name = 'White',stock_wash_id =
>   '0',image_path =
>   'assets/1/image_01232018162048952300.png',stock_division_status =
>   '1',stock_end_date = '2017-12-22',size_update_date = '2018-01-12
>   12:25:48',stock_category_id = '1',created_date = '2018-01-12
>   12:01:11',updated_date = '2018-01-12 12:01:11',stock_category_status =
>   '1',fob_cost = '520',seller_location_id = '1',listing_created_date =
>   '2018-01-23 09:20:48'}
>                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1477)
>                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:812)
>                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1424)
>                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
>                                                          at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
>                                                          at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
>                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
>                                                          at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8762)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3172)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1520)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4318)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4276)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4615)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4583)
>                                                          at com.adverscribe.bookyourstock.activities.HomeActivity$3.onResponse(HomeActivity.java:119)
>                                                          at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6349)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)

Answer (score 0):

Does the `ProductsItem` class serializable? If not, it will not serialize and will throw errors at runtime.  Make the `ProductsItem` class implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of casting products as Serializable, you have to create serializable class like this:

```
public class ProductsItem implements Serializable{
.
.
.
}
```

for sending data via intent:

```
intent.putExtra("category", products);
```

using it in destination activity to get data:

```
List<ProductsItem> items=
               (List<ProductsItem>)getIntent.getSerializable("caregory");
```

Answer (score 0):

Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized. All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable. The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to identify the semantics of being serializable.

You need to serialize your ProductsItem class

```
public class ProductsItem implements Serializable
```

While sending your serializable object is intent use

```
intent.putExtra("PRODUCT_ITEM", products);
```

To retrieve content use

```
List<ProductsItem> productItemList=
               (List<ProductsItem>)getIntent.getSerializable("PRODUCT_ITEM");
```

Although Parcelable is much better for Serialization. Parcelable is well documented in the Android SDK; serialization on the other hand is available in Java. It is for this very reason that Android developers prefer Parcelable over the Serialization technique.

·         In Parcelable, developers write custom code for marshaling and unmarshaling so it creates less garbage objects in comparison to Serialization. The performance of Parcelable over Serialization dramatically improves (around two times faster), because of this custom implementation.

·         Serialization is a marker interface, which implies the user cannot marshal the data according to their requirements. In Serialization, a marshaling operation is performed on a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) using the Java reflection API. This helps identify the Java objects member and behavior, but also ends up creating a lot of garbage objects. Due to this, the Serialization process is slow in comparison to Parcelable